# Assign value to variable when condition is met in Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Im having a bit of a struggle with processing dataframes.
I have been giving a problem to assign movie title with the correct movie using a Dataframe. I shall return the title of one specific movie  when the conditions using the dataframe.
The problem is quite basic, i am given a variable with the name "movie xxx" with the x's being a number between 0-100.
When there is a match in the "movie_name" column the title of that match should be returned.

The dataframe contains specific information in 10 columns, example of information is movie lenght, Data size, subtitles. But i have narrow it down to only getting the "title" column and the "movie_name" column.

```
Title                 Movie_name


Lord of the rings     Movie 089.mp4
Star Wars             Movie 024.mp4
Hello world           Movie 001.mp4
...                   ...
```

```
def get_movie_title(img_name,df_img):
    for name in df_img['movie']:
        if name == img_name:
            m_title = df_img['title']
        else:
            continue
    return m_title
```

So for say the movie 089.mp4 is given to me i want to find the match, and  to return the title for example "Lord of the rings" in the variable "m_title"

Right now the variable m_title returns all titles that is presented in the column "title"

Comment: can you please post a sample dataframe and expected output for clarity

Answer (score 0):

i'm not sure to understand what you want but thi scould help you

```
film_title=df_img.iloc[np.where(df_img["movie"]==img_name)]['title']
```